# Cannot get property '?' on null object error when flutter build apk

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, mobile

In my case I run **flutter build apk -t lib/main_dev.dart  --release --flavor=dev** command to build a release APK, I have setup build flavors in my project. But after I run that command it gives "**A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.> Cannot get property '?' on null object**" error. Here is my app level build.gradle file,

```js
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
                                                                                                                                 
    lintOptions {                                                                                                                            
        checkReleaseBuilds false                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 │
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.getin.app***"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "app"

    productFlavors {
        dev {
            dimension "app"
            versionNameSuffix "-dev"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "GetIn Dev"
            resValue "string", "facebook_app_id", "5982**********"
            resValue "string", "facebook_client_token", "d8f78c******************"
            resValue "string", "fb_login_protocol_scheme", "fb*****************"
        }
        prod {
            dimension "app"
            applicationId "com.getin.app"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "GetIn"
            resValue "string", "facebook_app_id", "5982**********"
            resValue "string", "facebook_client_token", "d8f78c******************"
            resValue "string", "fb_login_protocol_scheme", "fb*****************"
        }
    }

}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics'
}
```

Here is the given error,
[image]

As the image, it shows error is on line number 42, in line number 42 it has this,

[image]